# JSTL/AngularJS how to deactivate the expression language for a specific value?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, jstl

I have a user interface that let the user enter any value he wants (string value)

The value can contain any characters including `{{` and `}}` such as `{{.}}` or `{{/}}`

Example of values

- `text{{.}}here`
- `text{{\}}here`

I have a jsp page that uses angularjs which displays this value using `<c:out value="${stringValue}"/>`

The error I have is

```
angular.js:15697 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [.] starting at [.].
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.3/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=.&p4=.
    at angular.js:138:1
    at AST.throwError (angular.js:16255:1)
    at AST.primary (angular.js:16143:1)
    at AST.unary (angular.js:16121:1)
    at AST.multiplicative (angular.js:16108:1)
    at AST.additive (angular.js:16099:1)
    at AST.relational (angular.js:16090:1)
    at AST.equality (angular.js:16081:1)
    at AST.logicalAND (angular.js:16073:1)
    at AST.logicalOR (angular.js:16065:1)
```

It's trying to evaluate `.` in `{{.}}`

I am finding a solution to deactivate the expression language in the text of the value `stringValue` so it will appear `text{{.}}here` without evaluating `{{.}}`

From what I found, we can deactivate the expression language for the whole jsp page by doing

`<%@ page isELIgnored ="true" %>` but I want to deactive it only for this value not for the whole page

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%@ page isELIgnored ="true" %>` is not the solution because the error is not in the JSP processing, but in the AngularJS processing.

For example, if you have a JSP page such as

```html
<h1><c:out value="${stringValue}"/><h1>
```

The JSP will generate an HTML page containing:

```html
<h1>Text{{.}}Text<h1>
```

Which is interpreted by angularJS, and raises an error.

The solution is to disable the angularJS interpretation, using the directive [`ngNonBindable`](https://%60https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable). angularJS will not interpret the content of an element with this directive.

```html
<h1 ng-non-bindable><c:out value="${stringValue}"/><h1>
```

Comment: Good catch! yes exactly it's an angularjs problem